# First row's inline style disappears when executed

Tags: css, html-table

I have this PHP page which echoes table-rows. I echo some of the rows with other styles than the rest, but when those rows with the other styles are echoed as first row, the styles totally disappear.

When I inspect the element, I see that no styles are set, nor the class on the element, even though that if another row with other styles comes after it (meaning after the first row), it won't have these problems at all.

PHP

```
if (condition)
    echo "<tr style='background-color: #FFC07D; opacity: 0.85;' class='note'><td>...</td></tr>";
else
...
```

PS: I should point out that the table is hidden until the user presses on a button

jQuery:

```
$('#table').slideToggle(500);
```

Comment: Is it correct to use single quotes instead of double quotes in this context? `style="background-col..."`

Comment: thanks...but no single quote works just fine..  :)

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the page source code, can you see the `style` and `class` attributes correctly written? Then the issue is probably in the CSS rather than PHP.

Are you using an external CSS sheet besides the `style` attribute? If so you should check if it has any `tr:first-child` directive.

An URL of a page with the issue would be the more efficient way to help you.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<table>
    <?php
        $i=10;
        if($i >= 9){
          echo "<tr style='background-color: #FFC07D; opacity: 0.85;' class='note'><td>This is a paragraph.</td></tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```